# Is xinetd configurable on HP-UX and AIX?

Tags: aix, hp-ux, xinetd, inetd

I know inetd is available on HP-UX and AIX.

on Linux, inetd is available for kernel 2.x and below, and xinetd is available for 3.x and higher.

On HP-UX and AIX, xinetd has no way to install or use.

Can this be used? Help me.

Comment: If you can compile and install it from source, then (most likely) you can use and configure it.

Answer (score 1):

On HP-UX and AIX you have own init daemon which take care about the tasks. Do not play with Linux software because you risk to broke your OS.

Better read how to create autostart jobs on those operating systems and use native way.

Moreover AIX use (mostly) BSD style to start/stop daemons, HP-UX use SYS V style for this task.

Comment: Though `init` and `inetd`/`xinetd` might be different components.